# How to copy and paste HTML/text by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, copy, paste

I want to copy a text that has the CSS class `copytext`
and want to paste on the same page that's has CSS class `pastehere`.

I am using the following code, but with no result.

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
   const elem = document.createElement('.copytext');
   elem.value = text;
   document.body.appendChild(elem);
   elem.select();
   document.execCommand('.pastehere');
   document.body.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get the value of an HTML

tag or something? with DOM Element innerHTML you can get the value of the Tag. eg:

html:

```
`<p id="myTag">hello world</p>`
```

javascript:

```
`let var1 = document.getElementById("myTag").innerHTML;`
```

the 'hello world' is now stored in the variable 'var1' and you can continue to work with it normally

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to copy text from all elements `.copytext` to the element `.pastehere`:

HTML:

```
<div class="copytext">Line 1</div>
<div class="copytext">Line 2</div>
<div class="copytext">Line 3</div>
```

JS:

```
function fun(text){
  let copiedText = "";
  text.forEach(element => {
    copiedText += element.textContent + "\n";
  });
  const resault = document.createElement('div');
  resault.classList.add('pastehere');
  resault.innerText = copiedText;
  document.body.appendChild(resault);
}

let copyFrom = document.querySelectorAll('.copytext');
fun(copyFrom);
```

You'll get:

```
<div class="pastehere">
    Line 1 <br>
    Line 2 <br>
    Line 3 <br>
</div>
```

2. If you want to create element with the text you pass to the function as an argument:

JS:

```
function fun(text){
  let resault = document.createElement('div');
  resault.classList.add('pastehere');
  resault.innerText = text;
  document.body.appendChild(resault);
}

let text = "My text";
fun(text);
```

You'll get:

```
<div class="pastehere">
    My text
</div>
```

!! Note that you can only type a tag name in `document.createElement('');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.getElementById("ID NAME")
```

To copy.

To change you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class-name").style[0] = "max-width: 10%;"
```